Why does this simple RK4 implementation yield the correct answer with a vertical shift?
It's been a long time since I looked at numerical methods. I decided to try to implement RK4 from scratch for fun, and integrate a simple sin wave. It... almost works. I get negative cosine, but shifted up vertically.
I got my equations from some old school project I still have around, but I also used the ones right on wikipedia. I believe they are equivalent, as the results are identical.
def rk4_step(f, t_i, y_i, h):
    k1 = h * f(t_i, y_i)
    k2 = h * f(t_i + 0.5 * h, y_i + 0.5 * k1)
    k3 = h * f(t_i + 0.5 * h, y_i + 0.5 * k2)
    k4 = h * f(t_i +  h, y_i + k3)

    y_next = y_i + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6
    return y_next

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    rate = 60
    dt = 1 / rate
    runtime = 2 * np.pi

    def func(t, y):
        return np.sin(t)

    t = np.arange(0, runtime, dt)   
    y_0 = func(t[0], y=None)

    y = np.asarray(len(t) * [y_0])
    for i in range(len(t) - 1):
        y[i + 1] = rk4_step(func, t[i], y[i], dt)
    
    plt.plot(t, func(t, y=None), label="y_prime")
    plt.plot(t, y, label="solution")
    plt.plot(t, -np.cos(t), label="-cos(t)")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


I'm hoping someone can spot my error in my equations (or explain why this error is expected because something theoretical I forgot about a long time ago). I've been staring at this for hours.

Edit:
Given the comment that my solution is just showing the constant of integration, and there is no current answer posted yet, I'd like to expand the question a bit...
I expected to not deal with a constant of integration since I defined the initial conditions $y_0 = sin(0)$. To my thinking (rusty as it may be), that should mean I get a solution that is not shifted...

There's no error. It is correct that $\int_{t=0}^x \sin t , dt = 1 - \cos x$. (In other words, you found $C$, haha.)

Oh, jeez. I'm so rusty. Thanks!

@BrianTung I edited the question to account for your comment. Basically, I thought defining the initial conditions should guarantee that the constant of integration for this solution would be zero.

ah!!!! I figured it out! I set the initial condition as y = sin(0) instead of y = -cos(0)

Collecting insights and comments:
Your ODE does not depend on $y$, so it reduces to quadrature and the RK4 method reduces to the Simpson quadrature rule.
An anti-derivative or primitive of $\sin x$ is indeed $-\cos x$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus $$\int_0^x\sin(t)\,dt=(-\cos x)-(-\cos 0)=1-\cos x.$$
You need of course to initializes with $y_0=y(0)$  (not with $y_0=f(0,y(0))$). Otherwise you get a different integration constant, resulting in a vertical shift of the graph between numerical and expected solution.
You have a good sampling density for the frequency $1$ of the sine, so you get a visually exact numerical solution with this method.
As your next exercise, try to integrate with the most minimal changes to your code the circle system $[\dot x,\dot y]=f(t,[x,y])=[-y,x]$, $[x_0,y_0]=[1,0]$.

Challenge accepted!
